# Passing a static member function as argument

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

I would like to store and update the default directory path which is used by `QFileDialog::getOpenFileName` and `QFileDialog::getSaveFileName`. For this purpose, I created wrapper functions around the two and a third common function:

```
QString GetSaveFile (QWidget *parent, const QString &title, const QString &desc)
{
    return GetFile (&QFileDialog::getSaveFileName, parent, title, desc);
}

QString GetOpenFile (QWidget *parent, const QString &title, const QString &desc)
{
    return GetFile (&QFileDialog::getOpenFileName, parent, title, desc);
}

QString GetFile (std::function <QString (QWidget *, const QString&, const QString&, const QString&, QString*, QFileDialog::Options)> func,
                 QWidget *parent, const QString &title, const QString &desc)
{
    // this produces C2064
    QString path = func (parent, title, CurrentDir, desc, 0, 0);
    if (!path.isEmpty())
        UpdateCurrentDir (QFileInfo (path).absoluteDir().path());
    return path;
}
```

However, during compilation, I get

```
error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 6 arguments
```

But my first argument *is* a function which takes 6 arguments. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't you use the `QFileDialog::saveState()` and `QFileDialog::restoreState()` functions?

Comment: Your code looks fine, are you sure that line is the one producing the error?

Comment: **vahancho**: Because in this case I couldn't use the static functions QFileDialog::getOpenFileName and QFileDialog::getSaveFileName. I could create a QFileDialog manually, yet I would like to know why I am getting an error in this case.

**Marco A.**: When I double-click on the error notification in MSVC, the cursor jumps to that line. The line number matches, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it. This has to do with the limits of MSVC for variadic functions, as described here:

[Does C++11 std::function limit the number of arguments a function pointer can have?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10092074/does-c11-stdfunction-limit-the-number-of-arguments-a-function-pointer-can-ha)

In MSVC, a variadic function cannot accept more than 5 arguments by default. Redefining `_VARIADIC_MAX` solved the problem:

```
#ifdef _VARIADIC_MAX
    #undef _VARIADIC_MAX
#endif
#define _VARIADIC_MAX 10
```